# Currently a Microsoft Money user on PC, need a replacement suitable for Mac

Tags: microsoft-money

I switched to a Mac a few years ago but kept my old PC Windows running -- only for my Microsoft Money program, which I have used for over a decade... I love it.
Now I need to retire the old PC and I am looking for the best Mac software or on-line finance program to replace Microsoft Money.
I guess whatever I use, I will have to re-enter a lot of data, as I won't be able to import the existing data from my PC on to my Mac, right?
I would appreciate some assistance with this!

Comment: Might be worth mentioning where you are in the world as there were a few country-specific versions of MS Money and that might make a difference to the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a drop-in replacement for MS Money, but I've tried a few of the Mac desktop programs. I settled on [Iggsoftware's iBank](http://www.iggsoftware.com/ibank/), which seems to do what I need it to do. It also appears to be able to import transactions from MS Money if you export your accounts as QIF files at the MS Money end, but I never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from Quicken for Mac to Moneydance, and have not regretted it.

I see only one weakness in MD compared with Quicken: its reporting is not very good.  Your information is all there and well organized, but sometimes it's hard work to extract it in a convenient form.

Of course a lot depends on what you need from the application, but I strongly recommend you take a look at MD before deciding.

Answer (score 0):

Long time Quicken user, but I have Bootcamp on my Mac, and one reason is so I can run Quicken Windows.

That's one solution. You didn't mention what version of the Mac OS you're running, but Bootcamp is one alternative if you have (or can purchase) a Windows license. Be advised, Bootcamp 4, which is available with OS 10.7 (Lion) and OS 10.8 (Mountain Lion), [officially supports Windows 7 only](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4818?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US#3).

Quicken running under Bootcamp isn't perfect, but it's better than any Mac version, and [Quicken 2013 has a mobile app](http://quicken.intuit.com/personal-finance-software/whats-new-quicken.jsp) that allows you to view your data & enter transactions via your mobile. The [Mac Version of Quicken has been panned by users](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003PDMNCC).

I do use Windows for work-related stuff, so I have a reason for running Windows besides using Quicken.

I've read that Intuit has a market share of more than 70% in the personal finance software sector, and at this point it seems pretty clear that they are not interested in pursuing a larger share via Mac users. So if we ever see a highly functional version of Quicken for the Mac OS, it won't be any time soon.

I've not used other products, but there are many reviews out there which rank them, and some consistently come to the front.

[Top 10 Reviews Mac Personal Finance Software 2013](http://personal-finance-software-review.toptenreviews.com/mac-personal-finance-software/);

[WeRockYourWeb Personal Finance Software Rankings](http://www.werockyourweb.com/best-personal-finance-software) includes many Web-based alternatives;

Personally, I'm not real enthusiastic about posting my personal financial data on someone's Web site. I have nothing to hide, but I just can't get comfortable with [cloud-based personal finance software providers that are combing through my data, Google-like, to generate revenue](http://www.bloomberg.com/apps/news?pid=newsarchive&sid=aWJnLqF0Y8zs). Too, it seems an unnecessary risk giving a third party a list of all my account numbers, user names, and passwords. I know that information is out there, if one has the right sort of access, but to my way of thinking, using a cloud-based personal finance software application makes it more out there.